# How to hide Whatsapi tx and rx response output on screen

Tags: php, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have googled this a lot and not found a single piece of answer....!

I am using whatsapi to send messages with PHP.

However, when i execute any of the functions including loginwithpassword() or sendmessage() it outputs respones with lines starting with tx. I want to integrate the api into my webiste and auto post certain inputs to some of my Whatsapp groups.

I use the following code

```
$username = "91xxxxxxxx"; //Mobile Phone prefixed with country code so for india it will be 91xxxxxxxx
$password = "Password";
$identity = strtolower(urlencode(sha1($username, true)));
$w = new WhatsProt($username, $identity, "WhatsApp Messaging", true); //Name your application by replacing "WhatsApp Messaging"
$w->connect();
$w->loginWithPassword($password);

$phone="91xxxxxxxxxxx";

$w->eventManager()->bind("onGetGroups", "onGetGroups");
$w->sendGetGroups();

function onGetGroups($phone,$groups)
{
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";

foreach($groups as $gr){

    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='gids[]' value='$gr[id]'>$gr[id] ->   $gr[subject]<br>";
}
echo "<textarea name='msg' rows='10' cols='40'></textarea>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='gmsub' value='Send Group Message'>";
echo "</form>";


}

if(isset($_POST['gmsub'])){
$msg=$_POST['msg'];
$groupc=$_POST['gids'];

$total=count($groupc);
    for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
        $gId=$groupc[$i];

        $w->sendMessage($gId, $msg);
    }
}
```

I dont want the outputs like the following on my screen...

```
tx  <stream:features>
tx    <readreceipts></readreceipts>
tx    <groups_v2></groups_v2>
tx    <privacy></privacy>
tx    <presence></presence>
tx  </stream:features>

tx  <auth mechanism="WAUTH-2" user="91xxxxxxxxxx">&£ºƒ91xxxxxxxxxn•Vv^¹ðÁ2EÎòƒ³oÎ¡1447256662</auth>

rx  <start from="s.whatsapp.net"></start>

rx  <stream:features></stream:features>

rx  <challenge>œÇÚ‰C¹WŒ™`¼%1Á™</challenge>

tx  <response>ó gÏD’—!°¶µpOðµ³ @³XH2înÆ/•[r</response>

rx  <success t="1447256780" props="4" kind="free" status="active" creation="1413023053" expiration="1476095053">9Ož¦n»ÃFáG¨È{'sÊM‚</success>

.................etc
```

I want to output only what i want on the screen. How do I suppress the tx and rx outputs on screen ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the DEBUG mode by changing the last parameter in first line `false` instead of `true`

Comment: Perfect and simple answer @dhaval. Thanks a ton ! I was starting to hate Stackoverflow as nobody was answering but only downvoting without giving reasons ! SO should penalize such negative voters and appreciate people like you who actually help !